# LinkedIn: How do you enter a 'carriage return' in the Summary section?

Tags: linkedin

How do you enter a carriage return (line break) in the Summary section of a LinkedIn profile? I've tried the 'enter' key and hitting spaces and nothing works. It just eliminates the carriage returns and spaces and truncates everything.

I want a profile a Summary that looks like this: https://www.linkedin.com/in/stevendavismba/

In this profile "My passion" has a line break before it. How did he do that?

Comment: I've been trying to do that, without success. A double line-feed is supposed to work, but it doesn't; `<br>` is silently ignored; other HTML fields are displayed, as is `%0A`. I conclude that either LinkedIn have got something wrong in a web-site update, or you need a premium subscription to allow it. Have you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer. When I click on my profile I get:

[image: Showing less]

This is the same as I've had before, but when I click on `Show more` it is suddenly formatted correctly:

[image: Showing more]

What I did was to create the `SUMMARY` line made very long with non-breaking space characters. My profile is:-

```
SUMMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Recent work: retailing systems, especially point-of-sale software for tills.

Previous work: communications systems and real-time control.

Specialities: Design and coding of and retailing real-time control systems.

Languages: C++, C, PL/1, Fortran, Algol.

Operating systems: Windows, Linux, Unix, proprietary.
```

The profile you quote in your link works because the first paragraph is longer that the space available in the `Show less` box, so you don't see any of the formatting failures.

So you have two answers, or rather work-rounds:-

1. Use a long heading, as I have done.
2. Write a long initial paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3/29/19, it seems to work simply to add trailing spaces to the first paragraph.  They didn't show up in the summary, but they forced the "Show More" box to materialize, which restored my desired formatting.  So you don't have to add actual content.

Like this:
Proven Principal Developer.(sp)(sp)(sp)...Direct inquiries only, please.

[image]

Thanks: AFH

Answer (score 0):

In topcard summary doesn't work. But I used windows charmap with the character "U+2002: En Space" - it's sometype of "tab space". But it was fine.
[image]

You can check the result here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/claudiuivanescu/